# The method assertEquals(String, String) is undefined for the type TestJunit

Tags: java, junit

I am new to JUnit.
I just started working on JUnit and i am getting following error.

**The method assertEquals(String, String) is undefined for the type TestJunit**

and my Javacode:

```
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertArrayEquals;

public class TestJunit {

    String message = "Hello World";
    MessageUtil messageutil = new MessageUtil(message);

    public void testPrintMessage()
    {
        assertEquals(message,messageutil.printMessage());

    }
}
```

please help me resolve this issue.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You imported

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertArrayEquals;
```

but not

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
```

You could also import every static member of `Assert` with

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
```

Without these, Java thinks you are calling the method `assertEquals` defined in the class the code is declared in. Such a method does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

For Junit 5, I had to add following dependencies in my spring boot pom.xml files.

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-runner</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score -3):

if importing doesn't work try saving before you run the code